# Static header and footer for Viewpager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I've created a Simple ViewPager Project. I'm trying to add one standard header (CardView) above the ViewPager and Two Buttons below the Viewpager. Adding CardView or Any other views (TextView) is not shows. ViewPager only Shows
Here is my default layout with my comments (tries)...

[image: In My Mind]

**activity_home.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="grabit.viewpageronly.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <!-- I Can't Add any views here if I added anything like TextView it doesn't Show up -->
    <!-- Some Standard CardView -->

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <!-- Two Button below Viewpager -->

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> Here What I've Tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
           <appbar ... />
                 <toolbar .... />

     <TextView  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello World"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Your **TextView** goes under your **ViewPager** , Put them in LinearLayout and your problem will be fixed

Comment: yeah I've tried enclosing my textview and viewpager with LinearLayout and RelativeLayout, In RelativeLayout I placed viewpager under textview (android:layout_below="@+id/textview")

Comment: @sathsh doesn't work ?

Comment: yeah same problem :-(

Comment: Look at this example https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare I use this and works perfectly add your textView and if doesnt work let me Know to help you

Comment: Thank you, Let me see this example :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101711/discussion-between-sathish-kumar-and-amir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you should add behavior to your **LinearLayout** instead of your **ViewPager**.

Following xml works , It's add **TextView** with red background on Top of your **viewPager** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:background="#f22"
        android:id="@+id/tes"
        android:text="this is test"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You saved my day! , Thanks a lot :-)